# Visual Studio 2013: Save/Build of typescript produces different javascript enum

Tags: visual-studio-2013, enums, typescript

When I save the typescript from visual studio, the enum values remain human readable.

example:

```
switch (color) {
   case Color.Red: break;
 }
```

remains as is but when I build the project, integer values are substituted so it becomes

```
switch (color) {
   case 1 /* Color.Red */: break;
}
```

I do have my enum defined in another enum.ts file and added a reference to it.

How do I get Save (Ctrl + S) and the build to produce the same javascript?

Comment: Because each time a team member opens the project, those js files gets checkout based on how they were saved the last time. I just need both methods to produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get Save (Ctrl + S) and the build to produce the same javascript?

Don't use `constant` enums (plain enums are okay). Then output for both will be the same.

If you are getting this error for plain enums check your typescript version. This was an issue only in TS 1.4 but is fixed since TS1.5 beta : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1812

Comment: They are plain enum. enum  eg. Color {Red, Green, Blue}

Comment: Are you sure you are on the latest version of TypeScript. This was an issue in TypeScript 1.4 : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1812#issuecomment-71583997

Comment: Yes, I am on TS 1.4.  My current workaround is to check in the code only after a build so that it will be in the build format vs (Ctrl + S). My guess is, TS can't be sure I am including the enums.js file so it is playing safe and just substituting the values. If only Ctrl + S did the same thing. If the TypeScript Module settings is changed to build for AMD, it will use the enum values. I am not using any Module system.